How to Deduce Template Parameter T from Another Type U in C++?
I simplified my class MyVector in C++ by combining the lvalue and rvalue constructors into a single universal reference constructor. However, this change has led to a problem: the template parameter T of my class cannot be deduced from the universal reference parameter U in the constructor.
Here’s the definition of my class:
template<typename T>
class MyVector {
public:
    std::vector<T> data;
    ...
    
    template<typename U>
    MyVector(U&& data) : data(std::forward<U>(data)) {}
};


The consequence of this limitation is that using my class becomes inconvenient. Instead of being able to instantiate it like this:
MyVector v = std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3});

I am forced to specify the template parameter explicitly:
MyVector<int> v = std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3});

Problem:
I would like to enforce that std::decay_t<U> must be a std::vector<T> and, in turn, deduce T from U. It’s important to note that I do not want to simply ignore the definition of this constructor if std::decay_t<U> != std::vector<T>, which I could achieve using std::enable_if. Instead, I want to bind std::decay_t<U> to std::vector<T> in a way that enforces equality between these types, allowing type deduction to take place. Is there a way to achieve this in C++ using type traits or other techniques?
What I have tried:
I tried to solve this problem by creating a method bind in the class MyVector that takes one parameter of type std::vector<T> and passing std::declval<std::decay_t<U>>() to this function. Unfortunately, this failed with an error indicating that the result of std::declval must be unused. I have no other ideas on how to bind U to std::vector<T> in a way that would allow for type deduction. Is there a way to achieve this in C++ using type traits or other techniques?

"I do not want to simply ignore the definition of this constructor if std::decay_t<U> != std::vector<T>" and "I want to bind std::decay_t<U> to std::vector<T> in a way that enforces equality between these types" I need to admit that I don't understand the problem. These two sentences seem to contradict each other in my opinion. Cound you add some examples of initialization and describe what should be the outcome. Would user-defined deduction guides work for you? Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/nrEfMGhs4

Could you give an example where T and U should work together and one where they shouldn't?

@DanielLangr In your example, you defined separate deduction guides for lvalue and rvalue arguments. I could define two separate constructors as well, but that solution isn't better. What I’m looking for is a way to enforce that the constructor parameter is a std::vector and deduce T without needing those separate definitions.

@Surt I want the constructor to only accept a std::vector argument, not any type that can be converted to std::vector. My goal is for the code to behave like defining two constructors: Vector(const std::vector&) and Vector(std::vector&&), but with just one definition. I want to enforce this strict type match.

@antoni "but that solution isn't better" Why it isn't better? What is the particular problem with having those two definitions?

I would do MyVector(std::vector<T> data) : data(std::move(data)) {}

You can add a deduction guide.
template <typename U>
MyVector(U) -> MyVector<typename U::value_type>;

You may optionally want to further restrict the constructor to only accept std::vector.
template<typename U> 
  requires std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, 
                          std::vector<typename std::decay_t<U>::value_type>>
MyVector(U&& data) : data(std::forward<U>(data)) {}


It should be MyVector(U) -> ... instead.

@PasserBy Sure? MyVector(U&&) -> worked for me.

U&& would require typename std::decay_t<U>::value_type.

@Jarod42 you are right, moreover std::decay_t is needed in the requires clause. Will fix.
